# How velocity progresses over time with a non-constant acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile, drag

> A $0.25\text{ kg}$ sphere of radius equal to $0.07\text{ meters}$ is dropped *from rest* from the top of a building.
>
> Granted that it will not hit the ground before, **when** and **after what distance** will it reach terminal velocity?
>
> Air density: $1.225\text{ kg/m}^3$
>
> Drag coefficient: $0.56$
>
> Please explain your thinking process.

**The concept that eludes me is how velocity progresses over time, before reaching its terminal velocity, when the acceleration is not constant.**

My best guess so far was to calculate its terminal velocity, using:

$F_d = 0.5  P C_d  A  V^2$

and equaling it to $mg$, getting:

$0.25 * 9.8 = 0.5 * 1.225 * 0.56 * 0.0308 * V^2$ <=>

<=> $V =  (2.45/0.0106)^{1/2} = 15.23$

(being:

$P$: air density

$C_d$: drag coefficient

$A$: reference area

$V$: relative velocity)

And now I'm not sure where to go next. This is what I've come with to answer the questions above:

If I know that the initial acceleration was  $0.25 * 9.8$ and its final acceleration is going to be 0, I calculated an average, constant acceleration of:

$(a_i - a_f)/2$ <=> $0 - 2.45/2 = 1.225$

With that in mind, I divided the calculated terminal velocity by its assumed constant acceleration:

$V_t / a = 15.23 / 1.225 = 12.433$ **sec**

Given that velocity equals distance over time, I found the distance at which Vt was reached using the average velocity between 0 (initial) and 15.23 (terminal) of 7.615:

$V = d/t <=> d = vt = 7.615*12.433 = 94.6773$ **m**

Now, I think this is a rather simplistic and probably wrong reasoning, so I would love to get some help!

Comment: Balancing forces, you start off with a differential equation of the form $\ddot{x}=k-\dot{x}^2$. This can be solved analytically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equations for an object moving linearly but with air resistance taken into account?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38218/)

Comment: Not that this is the only problem, but you've made a few minor math errors here. You might want to check your calculations again