# Object moving against drag: is location equal to $ln(time + c)$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, drag

I'm creating an asteroids game. For player movement, I want the spaceship to be slowed down as if by a drag force, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics), and only the drag force. The magnitude of the drag force is proportional to $v^2$, and I decree that all other parameters are constant in the fantasy world I'm building.

Since force is proportional to mass by acceleration and the mass of the spaceship is constant, the acceleration is proportional to $-v^2$; negative as the force is in the opposite direction of the velocity.

The acceleration is the derivative of velocity, so $\frac{dv}{dt} = -c_m v^2$. This is a separable differential equation, solvable as $-c_m \int (v^{-2})dv = \int 1\, dt$, implying $c_m v^{-1} = t + c_i$ or equivalently $v = \frac{c_m}{t + c_i}$. I choose $c_m$ and I know $v$ at time $t = 0$, so I can calculate $c_i$.

I am told that given the form of $v$ as a function of $t$, the location of the spaceship as a function of time will be on the form $c_m \ln (t + c_i)$—in general, $\int \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)} dt = \ln|f(t)| + c$, but I'm limiting myself to $t > 0$ (and I can pick $c_m$ such that $c_i \geq 0$), so I can omit the absolute value.

Did I botch any of the physics or math? Is the location as a function of time calculated correctly?

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* Jonas Kolker! As written, your question is "Not suited for this site" (*check my work* type questions are considered *off-topic* [by the community](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6097/9887)). You might edit your question such that it is more of a conceptual physics question.

Comment: Actually, your question may have been answered [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/38227/9887) quite a few years ago.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, that answers my question perfectly. About on/off-topic-ness, what's the smallest change that would make my question on-topic? Removing my own calculations and just asking "what's location(t) vs. drag?" From my perspective that goes against the pop-up when I asked the question which said "show your research"—my thinking in math form _is_ exactly that research, I would think. Advice is very welcome.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri, is there a way to efficiently find answers to specific questions in this forum, particularly subject matter that was answered some time ago?